# Rails gem - geoipcity is not being included in the application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation, rubygems

I installed the geoip_city gem, and i tested the gem in irb... Now when I am using the gem in the application I get an error

`uninitialized constant ApplicationController::GeoIPCity`

I guessed it is because I did not add the line

`require geoip_city`

So I tried adding the line to the function I used the code in, but then I got the error

`No such file -- geoip_city`

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have your require rubygems before ?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'geoip_city'
```